# Domain inside Domain

Tags: grails, groovy

I have two Domain class:-

```
class Product {
  ProductType productType
  int openingQuantity
  int unitQuantity
  Date dateCreated
  Date lastUpdated
  boolean active
  static constraints = {
    productType(blank:false,nullable:false)
    openingQuantity(blank:false, nullable:false)
    unitQuantity(blank:false, nullable:false)
    active(nullable:false)
    dateCreated()
    lastUpdated()
  }
}
```

and

```
class ProductType {
  String name
  Date dateCreated
  Date lastUpdated

  static constraints = {
    name(nullable:false, blank:false,maxSize:50,validator: {
      return !ProductType.findByNameIlike(it)
    })
    dateCreated()
    lastUpdated()
  }
}
```

when i am in create.gsp of Product. it shows productType as id in drop down. but my requirement is to show ProductType name in the drop down. can anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override toString on your ProductType class;

```
String toString() { name }
```

Or, assuming you're using the default scaffolding, change:

```
<g:select name="productType.id"
          from="${com.ten.hp.his.pharmacy.ProductType.list()}"
          optionKey="id"
          value="${productInstance?.productType?.id}" />
```

By adding `optionValue`, so it looks like:

```
<g:select name="productType.id"
          from="${com.ten.hp.his.pharmacy.ProductType.list()}"
          optionKey="id"
          optionValue="name"
          value="${productInstance?.productType?.id}" />
```

Comment: Yes i can do that but i dont want to do it in domain. can you please suggest some thing in view?

Comment: @AB What tags are you currently using to show the field in the view?  Maybe the code for the view would help (rather than just posting your domain) if that's where you want the change to be applied?

Comment: </td>
                                <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: productInstance, field: 'productType', 'errors')}">
                                    <g:select name="productType.id" from="${com.ten.hp.his.pharmacy.ProductType.list()}" optionKey="id" value="${productInstance?.productType?.id}"  />
                                </td> . this is generated by default scaffolding. it is showing the product type id as dropdown.

Comment: @AB Add `optionValue="name"` to the `g:select`